# Spring MVC URI template problem

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC 3 on Tomcat 6, I can't seem to get RequestMappings of the form /x/y/z to work.  /x/y seems to work fine and that's what all the example in docs show.

For example, why does this work

```
@RequestMapping(value="/browse/{categoryName}");
```

but this is doesn't work:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/browse/category/{categoryName}");
```

Browsing to http://localhost:8080/myapp/browse/category/books generates a HTTP 404 from Tomcat.  The method looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class BrowseController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/browse/category/{categoryName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showCategory(@PathVariable("categoryName") String categoryName, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("categoryName", categoryName);
        return "Browse";
    }
}
```

I see this message in the Tomcat output window in Netbeans 6.9:

```
Nov 14, 2010 2:02:03 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/browse/category/model] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

EDIT:  added more tracing info from the log.  Please disregard the timestamps since this questions was edited over two days.

Upon deploying the app:

```
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:28 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Nov 15 21:33:28 EST 2010]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:28 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@143c423: defining beans [browseController,homeController,showController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0,viewResolver]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ea763a
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/browse] onto handler 'browseController'
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/browse/*] onto handler 'browseController'
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/home] onto handler 'homeController'
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/home/*] onto handler 'homeController'
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/show] onto handler 'showController'
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/show/*] onto handler 'showController'
Nov 15, 2010 9:33:29 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 501 ms
```

When I made the call to http://localhost:8080/myapp/browse/category/model,

```
Nov 15, 2010 9:34:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/browse/category/model] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

And here's my web.xml dispatcher config:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

So is there any reason why I URI pattern works but the other doesn't?

Comment: are you sure `{categoryName}` holds `books` ??

Comment: What do you mean? What else would it hold?

Comment: @Sajee: Which version of Spring do you use?

Comment: What is the mapping for your dispatcher servlet? is it `/*`? If not you may need to qualify the URL properly.

Comment: @Teja,  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed on another thread:
[spring-mvc: how to map URI templates in the form of "a/b/{c}"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196577/spring-mvc-how-to-map-uri-templates-in-the-form-of-a-b-c)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a request mapping for the browse controller.  Try this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/browse")
public class BrowseController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/category/{categoryName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showCategory(@PathVariable("categoryName") String categoryName, Model model)
    { 
        model.addAttribute("categoryName", categoryName);
        return "Browse";
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that and sadly that produces an HTTP 404 as well.

Comment: do you have <mvc:annotation-driven/> in your spring config?  if no, that will be a problem.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary with Spring 3.  As noted in my original question, annotations are working exception the specific one that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL pattern should be /* in the servlet mapping.

Comment: After I made that change, I get 404s for everything.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps I would need to enable logging?  And where the log file would be located?

Comment: add log4j.properties to your classes and add the     <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
to your web.xml file

Comment: I added the log output to my original post above.  Any clues?