# spring-mvc: how to map URI templates in the form of "a/b/{c}"?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I can get a URI template in the form of "/a/b" or "/a/{b}" to work. But when I try "/a/b/{c}", I get a HTTP 404 and a message in the log in the form of "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/a/b/c]..."  But I see these message in the log also which leads me to believe that the mappings are correct...?

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/a] onto handler 'AController'
Nov 16, 2010 12:18:39 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/a/*] onto handler 'AController'
Nov 16, 2010 12:18:39 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
```

I noticed all [the examples in the spring-mvc docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) show URI templates in the form of "/a/{b}" or /a/{b}/c/{d}". So is "/a/b/{c}" not possible? Is there anything I need to configure in web.xml to make this happen? Or can some (mis)configuration prevent that pattern from being mapped? Currently my dispatcher servlet is mapped to:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class AController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/a/b/{c}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView show() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("A");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Accessing http://localhost:8080/myapp/a/b/c returns a 404 and I see this in the log:

```
Nov 16, 2010 12:19:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/a/b/c] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Any ideas on how I get my URI pattern to get mapped correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this happens only when `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` is used as a handler mapping.

Annotated controllers are usually used with `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, and in that case everything works fine.

**EDIT:**
Actually, it looks like a legitimate behaviour of `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`. It maps `aController` to `/a/*` rather than `/a/**`, therefore only one level of path hierarchy is accepted. And again, if you need full flexibility, use `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`.

Comment: I updated my post above to include more log info.  Looks like AbstractUrlHandlerMapping is being used?

Comment: @Sajee:  `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` is a base class. Log from your previous question clearly says the `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` is used.

Comment: @axtavt: thanks for your help.  I'm new to Spring so can you specify how I would use DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping?  Also why does the docs says "In previous versions of Spring, users were required to define HandlerMappings in the web application context to map incoming web requests to appropriate handlers. With the introduction of Spring 2.5, the DispatcherServlet enables the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping, which looks for @RequestMapping annotations on @Controllers. Typically, you do not need to override this default mapping, unless you need to override the default property values."?

Comment: Docs link the above quote: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping


To me, it sounds like DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is already enabled?

Comment: @Sajee: Defaults are not applied if you declared some handler mappings manually. Since logs in your previous question show that `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` is declared, perhaps you somehow declared it, so you need to remove that declaration.

Comment: @axtavt:  I did have ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping declared in my dispatcher-servlet.xml.  I added it to enable the controller mapping from class names.  If I remove it, my controllers don't get mapped.  What can I do here?  I would like to use the convention-over-configuration features ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping but also get more than one level of path hierarchy.  What are my options?

Comment: @Sajee: Since you already have a full path in `@RequestMapping` (i.e. `/a/b/{c}`), `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` is redundant, `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` should have the same behaviour.

Comment: @axtavt: So is there any reason why I'm getting 404s when I access any URL on my site after I remove ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping?  My site is broken w/o it.  Any idea how I can fix?

Comment: @axtavt: The problem that I'm now getting is that /a/b/c is now getting mapped correctly after I removed ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping but it can't resolve the view or map the .jsp: "Nov 16, 2010 2:54:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TT-SpringMVC/WEB-INF/jsp/A.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'"  

If I can fix that, the I should be good.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sajee: Are you sure you have `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`, not `/*`?

Answer (score 0):

can you try the below,

@RequestMapping(value = "/a/b/{c}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

```
public ModelAndView show(@PathParam("c") String c) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("A");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.  I think @axtavt is on the right path above with the controller only being mapped to /a/* rather than /a/**.